# How to view the hidden files in Visual Studio Code Editor Group window?

Tags: listview, view, format, editor, visual-studio-code

Assume I've opened 10 files in Visual Studio Code Editor Group window. Only 5 are visible, remaining files are hidden. I am not able to scroll horizontally and find the hidden files. Is there a short cut or plug-in to view the hidden files in drop down. I am looking for something similar to CTRL+E in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you want but fast are the hotkeys for toggling through opened editors.  See them under the Go/Switch Editor menu.

Comment: Thank you Mark. This is what i was looking for.

Comment: In that case I'll make it into an answer - I thought you wanted a listview of some sort.

Comment: Please add that as your answer. i will delete mine. I'll mark yours answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to see a listview of opened editors - beyond that in the "Open Editors" list in the left panel.

> // Number of editors shown in the Open Editors pane. Set it to 0 to hide the pane.
>     "explorer.openEditors.visible": 9,
>
> // Controls if the height of the open editors section should adapt
>   dynamically to the number of elements or not.
>   "explorer.openEditors.dynamicHeight": true,

Otherwise try the hotkeys listed under Go/Switch Editor menu:

> Next Editor       Ctrl/Cmd + Page Down
>
> Previous Editor        Ctrl/Cmd + Page Up

Answer (score 0):

- Next Used Editor in Group -> Ctrl + Tab
- Previous Used Editor Group -> Ctrl + Shift + Tab
- Next Editor -> Ctrl + Page Down
- Previous Editor -> Ctrl + Page Up

(I just mentioned the hotkeys suggested by Mark (In comment)).

Answer (score 0):

With [Visual Studio Code 1.44 (March 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/16b282c897cdae0398763a31740d288d331309f6/release-notes/v1_44.md#file-explorer-can-show-hidden-files), you will at least see them in the File Explorer

> ### File Explorer can show hidden files
>
> If a file is hidden (via the `files.exclude` setting) **but it is open and visible in the editor**, the file is shown in the `File Explorer` along with its parent chain.
>
> Those files and their parents are displayed in the Explorer using a dimmed color as long as the file is visible in the editor area.